# Getting current collections in MongoDB from MongooseJS 5.x

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on a demo project that resets my mongodb collections every hour. I got how use cron in my node project. What I can't figure out is how to get the collection names. I've looked at other solutions but it seems that there was a way in earlier versions of mongoose but not V5.

`console.log(mongoose.connection.db) // Undefined`

So, basically, I want to be able to get an array of the current collections to programmatically drop them and reseed the DB.

```
async function reloadDb(){
// Get collection names
const collectionNames = await mongoose.connection.db    //undefined but I want array
// Map through results....
{...}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get collections using `Object.keys(mongoose.connection.collections);`

Also, to reset DB programatically loop over every collection you can do:

```js
const collections = mongoose.connection.collections;
for (const key in collections) {
    const collection = collections[key];
    await collection.deleteMany();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In similar situations, I always go low as possible, for example, using MongoDB client directly, and dropping collections approximately like this, **(this answer is appropriate for dropping, is not quite clear if dropping or clear of collections was needed)**:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb')
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient
const connectionURL = 'mongodb://localhost'

const client = new MongoClient(connectionURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

const drop = async (databaseName) => {
    await client.connect().then(() => {
        const db = client.db(databaseName);
        const collections = db.listCollections();
        collections.forEach(element => {
            db.dropCollection(element.name);
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("ERROR:", error) // or some logger
    })
}

exports.drop = drop;
```